# After submitting the form and validating TOKEN JWT, the Vue JS instance is loaded again

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuex, vue-router

I'm working on an HTML Login page that has Vue JS implementations. I'm using JWT for the authentication part, which is working correctly on the backend part.

However, when I submit the login page with username and password, I get the impression that the instance of the VUE or the HTML page is reloaded again, so that the user cannot leave the Login screen.

I'm not sure that's what's happening, but I'd like your help in trying to resolve this.

Can I control it so that instead of calling the instance again, I can continue navigating the routes?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>BRXMind - Log In</title>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/jwt-decode@1.5.0/"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuex/3.2.0/vuex.min.js"></script>


    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta content="A fully featured admin theme which can be used to build CRM, CMS, etc." name="description" />
    <meta content="Coderthemes" name="author" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/images/favicon.ico">
    <link href="assets/css/icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="assets/css/app.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="light-style" />
    <link href="assets/css/app-dark.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="dark-style" />
</head>

<body class="authentication-bg pb-0" data-layout-config='{"darkMode":false}'>
    <div id="appLogin" >
        <Dash></Dash>
        <div v-if="alert.message" :class="`alert ${alert.type}`">{{alert.message}}</div>
        <div class="auth-fluid">
            <div class="auth-fluid-form-box">
                <div class="align-items-center d-flex">
                    <div class="card-body">

                        <div class="auth-brand text-center text-lg-start">
                            <a href="/login" class="logo-dark">
                                <span><img src="assets/images/brxmind-logo.png" alt="" height="90"></span>
                            </a>
                            <a href="/login" class="logo-light">
                                <span><img src="assets/images/brxmind-logo-light.png" alt="" height="90"></span>
                            </a>
                        </div><br><br><br><br><br>

                        <h4 class="mt-0">Entrar</h4>
                        <p class="text-muted mb-4">Digite seu endereço de e-mail e senha para acessar a conta.</p>

                        <form name="f" @submit.prevent="handleSubmit" class="login-form">
                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <label for="inputEmail" class="form-label">Endereço de e-mail</label>
                                <input v-model="email" class="form-control" type="email" name="email"
                                    id="inputEmail" required="" placeholder="Digite seu email">
                            </div>
                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <!--<a href="pages-recoverpw-2.html" class="text-muted float-end"><small>Esqueceu seu senha?</small></a>-->
                                <label for="inputPassword" class="form-label">Senha</label>
                                <input v-model="password" class="form-control" type="password" name="password"
                                    required="" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Digite sua senha">
                                <div class="container messageValidationError">
                                    <div th:if="${param.error}" class="error"><small class="form-text"
                                            style="color: red; margin-left: -10px">Email e/ou senha inválidos.</small>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!--<div class="mb-3">
                                <div class="form-check">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="checkbox-signin">
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="checkbox-signin">Lembrar</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>-->
                            <div class="d-grid mb-0 text-center">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary" name="button"><i class="mdi mdi-login"></i> Entrar
                                </button>
                            </div>

                        </form>

                        <footer class="footer footer-alt">
                            <p class="text-muted">2021 © BRAXXY - BRX Mind </p>
                        </footer>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="auth-fluid-right text-center">
                <div class="auth-user-testimonial">
                    <h2 class="mb-3">Bem vindo ao BRXMind!</h2>
                    <p class="lead"> BRXMind é um software livre, gerenciador de projetos baseados na web e ferramenta
                        de
                        gerenciamento de bugs. Ele contém calendário e gráficos de Gantt para ajudar na representação
                        visual
                        dos projetos e seus deadlines (prazos de entrega). Ele pode também trabalhar com múltiplos
                        projetos.
                        O design do Redmine foi influenciado pelo Trac, um pacote de software semelhante.
                        O BRXMind é escrito usando o framework Spring. Ele é multiplataforma e integra com a maioria dos
                        Banco de Dados.
                        Além de ser um software multiplataforma, também possibilita o uso integrado com vários
                        repositórios
                        tais como Svn, Git, Mercurial, Darcs, Cvs e Bazaar.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        
        const API_URL = 'http://localhost:8080';
        const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
        const initialState = user ? { status: { loggedIn: true }, user } : { status: {}, user: null };
        const userService = {
            login,
            logout,
            getAll
        };


        function login(email, password) {
            console.log('ESTOU NO LOGIN')
            const requestOptions = {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                body: JSON.stringify({ email, password })
            };
            
            return fetch(API_URL + '/auth', requestOptions)
                .then(handleResponse)
                .then(user => {
                    // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
                    console.log('LOGIN SUCCESFUL')
                    if (user.token) {
                        console.log('GUARDA TOKEN STORAGE!!!')
                        // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
                    }

                    return user;
                });
        }

        function logout() {
            console.log('ESTOU NO LOGOUT')
            // remove user from local storage to log user out
            localStorage.removeItem('user');
        }

        function getHealth() {
            console.log('ESTOU NO getHealth')
            const requestOptions = {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: authHeader()
            };
            console.log('HEADER', requestOptions.headers)
            return fetch(`${API_URL}/health`, requestOptions).then(handleResponse);
        }
        function getAll() {
            console.log('ESTOU NO getHealth')
            const requestOptions = {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: authHeader()
            };
            console.log('HEADER', headers)
            return fetch(`${API_URL}/health`, requestOptions).then(handleResponse);
        }

        function handleResponse(response) {
            console.log('ESTOU NO handleResponse')
            
            
            return response.text().then(text => {
                console.log('text', text)
                const data = text && JSON.parse(text);
                if (!response.ok) {
                    if (response.status === 401) {
                        console.log('DEU 401 VOU FAZER RELOAD---------------------------------------')
                        // auto logout if 401 response returned from api
                        logout();
                        location.reload(true);
                    }

                    const error = (data && data.message) || response.statusText;
                    return Promise.reject(error);
                }

                return data;
            });
        }
        function authHeader() {
            console.log('ESTOU NO AUTH HEADER HELPERS!!!')
            // return authorization header with jwt token
            let user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));

            console.log('USER TOKEN ACESS', user.accessToken)
            console.log('USER TOKENB', user.token)
            if (user && user.token) {

                return { 
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + user.token 
                };
            } else {
                console.log('ERRO!!!')
                return {};
            }
        }

        const alert = {
            namespaced: true,
            state: {
                type: null,
                message: null
            },
            actions: {
                success({ commit }, message) {
                    commit('success', message);
                },
                error({ commit }, message) {
                    commit('error', message);
                },
                clear({ commit }) {
                    commit('clear');
                }
            },
            mutations: {
                success(state, message) {
                    state.type = 'alert-success';
                    state.message = message;
                },
                error(state, message) {
                    state.type = 'alert-danger';
                    state.message = message;
                },
                clear(state) {
                    state.type = null;
                    state.message = null;
                }
            }
        }

        const authentication = {
            namespaced: true,
            state: initialState,
            actions: {
                login({ dispatch, commit }, { email, password }) {
                    console.log('DISPATCH DO LOGIN')
                    commit('loginRequest', { email });

                    userService.login(email, password)
                        .then(
                            user => {
                                console.log('TOKEN VALIDADO COM SUCESSO')
                                commit('loginSuccess', user);
                                console.log('USER', user)
                                console.log('VOU MANDAR ROTA COM SUCESSO')
                                
                                console.log('ESTOU LOGADO?[', initialState.status )
                                
                                //router.push('/dashboard');
                                //window.location.replace("http://localhost:8080/health")
                                
                                
                            },
                            error => {
                                commit('loginFailure', error);
                                dispatch('alert/error', error, { root: true });
                            }
                        );
                },
                logout({ commit }) {
                    console.log('DISPATCH LOGOUT')
                    userService.logout();
                    commit('logout');
                }
            },
            mutations: {
                loginRequest(state, user) {
                    console.log('loginRequest ')
                    state.status = { loggingIn: true };
                    state.user = user;
                },
                loginSuccess(state, user) {
                    console.log('loginSuccess ')
                    state.status = { loggedIn: true };
                    state.user = user;
                },
                loginFailure(state) {
                    console.log('loginFailure ')
                    state.status = {};
                    state.user = null;
                },
                logout(state) {
                    console.log('logout MUTATIONS')
                    state.status = {};
                    state.user = null;
                }
            }
        }

        const users = {
            namespaced: true,
            state: {
                all: {}
            },
            actions: {
                getAll({ commit }) {
                    console.log('users getAll')
                    commit('getAllRequest');

                    userService.getAll()
                        .then(
                            users => commit('getAllSuccess', users),
                            error => commit('getAllFailure', error)
                        );
                }
            },
            mutations: {
                getAllRequest(state) {
                    console.log('getAllRequest')
                    state.all = { loading: true };
                },
                getAllSuccess(state, users) {
                    console.log('getAllSuccess')
                    state.all = { items: users };
                },
                getAllFailure(state, error) {
                    console.log('getAllFailure')
                    state.all = { error };
                }
            }
        }

        const store = new Vuex.Store({
            modules: {
                alert,
                authentication,
                users
            }
        });

         // Define a new global component called button-counter
         var dash = Vue.component('Dash', {
       
            data() {
                return {
                count: 0
                }
            },
            template: `<p> </p>`
            
            
        })

        
         new VueRouter({
           
        });

        router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
            console.log('ESTOU NO BEGORA EACH ROUTER')
            // redirect to login page if not logged in and trying to access a restricted page
            var publicPages = ['/login','/health'];
            const authRequired = !publicPages.includes(to.path);
            console.log('TO PATH', to.path)
            console.log('authRequired', authRequired)
            const loggedIn = localStorage.getItem('user');
            console.log('JA TENHO TOKEN?', loggedIn)
            
            if (authRequired && !loggedIn) {
                console.log('NÂO AUTORIZADO!!!! AUTH REQUIRED')
                return next('/login');
            }
            
            console.log('VOU DAR NEXT!!!')
            
            next();
        })

       

       
        new Vue({
            
            el: '#appLogin',
            store,
            dash,
            
            
            data() {
                return {
                    email: '',
                    password: '',
                    submitted: false
                }
            },
            
            created(){
                this.$store.dispatch('authentication/logout');
            },
            computed: {
                alert() {
                    return this.$store.state.alert
                },
                loggingIn() {
                    console.log('ESTOU LOGADO?', this.$store.state.authentication.status.loggingIn)
                    return this.$store.state.authentication.status.loggingIn;
                },
            },
            watch: {
                
                $route(to, from) {
                    // clear alert on location change
                    this.$store.dispatch('alert/clear');
                }
            },
            methods: {
                handleSubmit(e) {
                    
                    this.submitted = true;
                    const { email, password } = this;
                    const { dispatch } = this.$store;
                    if (email && password) {
                        dispatch('authentication/login', { email, password });
                    }
                }
            }


        }).$mount('#appLogin')


      
        
    </script>
    <script src="assets/js/vendor.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/app.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/scripts/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/scripts/vue-router.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/scripts/vuex.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/scripts/vuex.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/scripts/axios.min.js"></script>
    





</body>

</html>
```

Notice in the image below that a redirect is done without any command from me

[image: Dev Tool]

Answer (score 0):

1. You are loading Vue and Vuex triple times
2. You are loading VueRouter twice
3. You are using Vue template syntax inside HTML - the browser will ignore the invalid syntax (which is only recognizable by Vue template compiler)
4. The `router` variable is not defined
5. You are instantiating VueRouter without any routes config and you are not attaching it to the root Vue instance

In short - you have bigger issues than the page reload.

Comment: Unfortunately I got the project that way already.

Fixed the problems pointed out, but my problem persists.

I tried looking everywhere and I can't find a solution.

I just needed it to go to /health after being authenticated :(

I don't know what I can do to stop it from reloading the page. @IVO GELOV

Comment: The code in your question still has errors - so we're not looking at your actual code. My advice is to use SFC but if you can't then at least move the Vue template syntax inside `<template>` tag and then reference it from your component(s).